# How to displays the value of dynamic arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

My array is like this :

```
$a = array(
    array('CXLDay' => 8,
        'CXLRemark' => array(),
        'CXLFee'    =>150
    ),
    array('CXLDay' => 5,
        'CXLRemark' => array(),
        'CXLFee'    =>100
    ),
);
```

I display it using code like this :

```
foreach($a as $key=>$value)
{
    echo 'Day = '.$value['CXLDay'].', ';
    echo 'Fee = '.$value['CXLFee'].'<br>'; 
}
```

But, If my array change like this :

```
$a = array(
    'CXLDay' => 8,
    'CXLRemark' => array(),
    'CXLFee'    =>553191.010000
);
```

There exist error like this :

> Notice: Undefined index: CXLDay...
>
> Notice: Undefined index: CXLFee...

This seems necessary plus condition, but I'm still confused

How to displays the value of dynamic arrays?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: the first one is multi leveled, the other one is flat, just add an if, either an `is_array` or just a simple `isset` checking the index

Comment: @Ghost,` if(isset($a['CXLDay'])){
  echo 'Day = '.$a['CXLDay'].', ';
     echo 'Fee = '.$a['CXLFee'].'<br>'; 
 }
 else{
  foreach($a as $key=>$value){
         echo 'Day = '.$value['CXLDay'].', ';
         echo 'Fee = '.$value['CXLFee'].'<br>'; 
     }
 }`. Like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code example would output both arrays in your example.

```
if(array_key_exists('CXLDay',$a)){
    echo 'Day = '.$a['CXLDay'].', ';
    echo 'Fee = '.$a['CXLFee'].'<br>'; 
}elseif(count($a) && array_key_exists('CXLDay',$a[0])){
    foreach($a as $key=>$value){
        echo 'Day = '.$value['CXLDay'].', ';
        echo 'Fee = '.$value['CXLFee'].'<br>'; 
    }
}
```

It would however always rely on the array key 'CXLDay' being present in the array.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652796/why-multiple-datepicker-not-working/39652870#39652870

Answer (score 0):

You missed something in your code...

from

```
$a = array(
    'CXLDay' => 8,
    'CXLRemark' => array(),
    'CXLFee'    =>553191.010000
);
```

to

```
$a = array(
        array('CXLDay' => 8,
            'CXLRemark' => array(),
            'CXLFee'    =>553191.010000
        )
);
```